# Foreach 3 columnas div

Tags: html, css, laravel-blade

Buenas comunidad tengo un problema que soy incapaz de resolver. tengo una colección que la quiero mostrar en 3 columnas ejmeplo:

```
noticia 1
noticia 2
noticia 3
noticia 4
noticia 5
noticia 6
noticia 7
noticia 8
```

Quiero que se listen los productos en 3 columnas, tal que así:

Ejemplo:

```
| left | center | right |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| noticia 1  | noticia 4    | noticia 7 |
| noticia 2  | noticia 5    | noticia 8 |
| noticia 3  | noticia 6    |  |
...
```

He probado a dividir el total de noticias / 3 para obtener el numero de noticias que me corresponde por columna, pero claro en el mismo foreach no consigo mostrar todas las noticias.

La otra opción es hacer 3 consultas por columna cosa que no veo optimo.

Comment: Yo veo en esta pregunta que la duda esta mas enfocada a HTML y CSS que a las otras etiquetas

Comment: disculpad es que estoy programando en laravel con blade, lo edito, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías apoyarte en una variable para hacer que cada 3 noticias impresas se considere una columna, luego con **CSS** haces que cada columna ocupe 1/3 del espacio y ya lo tendrías.

El **PHP** para imprimir una estructura **HTML** que te sirviera para ese caso podría ser:

```
$noticias = ['noticia1', 'noticia2', 'noticia3', 'noticia4', 
             'noticia5', 'noticia6', 'noticia7', 'noticia8',];
$contador = 0;

echo '<div class="noticias">';

foreach ($noticias as $noticia) {
    $contador++;
    
    if ($contador === 1) {
        echo '<div class="columna">';
        echo '<div class="noticia">';
        echo $noticia;
        echo '</div>';
    }
    else if ($contador === 3) {
        echo '<div class="noticia">';
        echo $noticia;
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
        
        $contador = 0;
    }
    else {
        echo '<div class="noticia">';
        echo $noticia;
        echo '</div>';
    }
}

echo '</div>';
```

De esta manera conseguimos que cada vez que el contador sea 1 se abra un `<div>` con la clase **columna** además de pintar la noticia, cuando sea 3 se imprime la noticia y seguidamente se cierra la columna y en caso de ser otro pues solamente se pinta la noticia.

Una vez tengas ese **HTML** es podrías usar **grid** para encolumnarlo.

```css
.noticias {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="noticias">
  <div class="columna">
    <div class="noticia">noticia1</div>
    <div class="noticia">noticia2</div>
    <div class="noticia">noticia3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="columna">
    <div class="noticia">noticia4</div>
    <div class="noticia">noticia5</div>
    <div class="noticia">noticia6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="columna">
    <div class="noticia">noticia7</div>
    <div class="noticia">noticia8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Con un pequeño cambio se podría contemplar cualquier número de noticias por columna. Dividiendo la cantidad de noticias entre 3 y redondeando hacia arriba obtendrías el número de noticias que necesitas en cada columna. Luego, en el bucle, en vez de cerrar la columna cuando llegue a 3 noticias pues usas ese cálculo de noticias por columna que hemos realizado con anterioridad:

```
$noticias = ['noticia1', 'noticia2', 'noticia3', 'noticia4', 
             'noticia5', 'noticia6', 'noticia7', 'noticia8',
             'noticia9', 'noticia10', 'noticia11', 'noticia12'];
$contador = 0;
$noticias_por_columna = ceil(count($noticias)/3);

echo '<div class="noticias">';

foreach ($noticias as $noticia) {
    $contador++;
    
    if ($contador === 1) {
        echo '<div class="columna">';
        echo '<div class="noticia">';
        echo $noticia;
        echo '</div>';
    }
    else if ($contador === $noticias_por_columna) {
        echo '<div class="noticia">';
        echo $noticia;
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
      
        $contador = 0;
    }
    else {
        echo '<div class="noticia">';
        echo $noticia;
        echo '</div>';
    }
}

echo '</div>';
```

Comment: El problema es que no siempre son 3 noticias por columna, si la query recibida puede tener 3, 4,10, 18 noticias.... por lo que me tiene que ajustar el mismo numero de noticias por columna dejando siempre la 3 columna el menor si no fueran pares.

Comment: Añadí una posible solución para tu caso.